# Mimic/Test Facebook Deauthorize POST

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook requires a public url to POST to in order to deauthorize your app for a user.

I am behind a firewall and do not wish to test this on my production environment, therefore has anyone managed to mimic this POST in a c# (or other) integration test?

It would involve building up a form with a field signed_request and encrypted to base64 and the posting it to my local web app to handle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find something similar for building the payload in Ruby which I've converted, here it is with an integration test:

This class builds the string that you will POST as request.form["signed_request"]

```
public class SignedRequest
  {
    public static string SignedRequestFor(string applicationSecret, string json)
    {
      // encode payload
      var payload = ToUrlBase64String(json);

      // create sig
      var Hmac = SignWithHmac(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload), UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(applicationSecret));
      var HmacBase64 = ToUrlBase64String(Hmac);

      // concat and return
      return HmacBase64.Concatenate(".", payload);
    }

    private static byte[] SignWithHmac(byte[] dataToSign, byte[] keyBody)
    {
      using (var hmacAlgorithm = new HMACSHA256(keyBody))
      {
        hmacAlgorithm.ComputeHash(dataToSign);
        return hmacAlgorithm.Hash;
      }
    }

    private static string ToUrlBase64String(string input)
    {
      byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
      return ToUrlBase64String(encodedBytes);
    }

    private static string ToUrlBase64String(byte[] input)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(input).Replace("=", String.Empty)
                                            .Replace('+', '-')
                                            .Replace('/', '_');
    }
  }
```

Small value object used by the test:

```
public class RequestEnvelope
  {
    public long user_id { get; set; }

    public string algorithm = "HMAC-SHA256";
  }
```

The test:

```
[Test]
public void CanDeauthorizeUser()
{
  var appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewsletterSubscriptionFacebookAppSecret"];

  var envelope = new RequestEnvelope { user_id = 123456 };

  var signedRequest = SignedRequest.SignedRequestFor(appSecret, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelope));

  var postData = "signed_request=" + signedRequest;
  byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

  var request = WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppWebUrl"] + "/SubscriptionHandler.ashx?a=deactivate");
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
  using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
    // Send the data.
    newStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    newStream.Close();
  }

  // Get the response.
  using (var response = request.GetResponse())
  {
    var status = ((HttpWebResponse) response).StatusDescription;

    // Get the stream containing all content returned by the requested server.
    using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {

      // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
      {

        // Read the content fully up to the end.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        Console.WriteLine("status: " + status);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Snippet from the Handler that I post to:

```
string signedRequestValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["signed_request"];
var items = SignedRequestParser.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewsletterSubscriptionFacebookAppSecret"], signedRequestValue);
```

And the code for parsing that (taken/modified from the codeplex facebook API):

```
public class SignedRequestParser
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Parses the signed request string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appSecret">The unique app hash known the provider and the developer</param>
    /// <param name="signedRequestValue">The encoded signed request value.</param>
    /// <returns>The valid signed request.</returns>
    public static Dictionary<string, string> Parse(string appSecret, string signedRequestValue)
    {
      Check.Require(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(signedRequestValue));
      Check.Require(signedRequestValue.Contains("."), "Invalid Signed Request");

      string[] parts = signedRequestValue.Split('.');
      var encodedValue = parts[0];
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(encodedValue))
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Signed Request");
      }

      var sig = Base64UrlDecode(encodedValue);
      var payload = parts[1];

      using (var cryto = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSecret)))
      {
        var hash = Convert.ToBase64String(cryto.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload)));
        var hashDecoded = Base64UrlDecode(hash);
        if (hashDecoded != sig)
        {
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Signed Request.");
        }
      }

      var payloadJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Base64UrlDecode(payload)));
      var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(payloadJson);
      return data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the base 64 url encoded string to standard base 64 encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encodedValue">The encoded value.</param>
    /// <returns>The base 64 string.</returns>
    private static string Base64UrlDecode(string encodedValue)
    {
      Check.Require(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encodedValue));

      encodedValue = encodedValue.Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').Trim();
      int pad = encodedValue.Length % 4;
      if (pad > 0)
      {
        pad = 4 - pad;
      }

      encodedValue = encodedValue.PadRight(encodedValue.Length + pad, '=');
      return encodedValue;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it in PHP:

```
<?php

function generateSignedRequest($data, $secret) {

    $payload = base64UrlEncode(json_encode($data));
    $signature = base64UrlEncode(hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true));

    return "$signature.$payload";
}

function base64UrlEncode($input) {
    $input = rtrim(base64_encode($input), '=');
    return strtr($input, '+/', '-_');
}

$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET_HERE";

$data = array(
    'algorithm' => 'HMAC-SHA256',
    'issued_at' => 1332162396,
    'user' => array(
        'country' => 'bg',
        'locale' => 'en_US'
    ),
    'user_id' => '100003387159594'
);

$signed_request = generateSignedRequest($data, $app_secret);

?>

<form action="deauthorize_callback.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="signed_request" value="<?php echo $signed_request?>" size="255" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send Request" />
</form>
```

If you have PHP in your local environment you can try submiting the form to your backend and see if it works. You just have to replace your app secret and user id in the data array.

Hope this helps, it worked for me so far.